# JSON - slashes not escaping

Tags: php, json

This is my PHP/Json script:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "test", "test") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("news") or die("Could not select database");

$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stories");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"success":true,"error":"","data":[{"schedule":'.json_encode ($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES).']}}';
*/
?>
```

The JSON displays properly; however, despite using JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES apostrophes still show, e.g.

It's a test!

when it should be:
It/'s a test!

How can I get this to work properly?

Comment: but... they don't need to be escaped

Comment: My JSON is based off this: http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?&name=Viking+FM

Comment: When I search for `'` in that file, I find unescaped apostrophes, as I would expect. I also find escaped `/` characters (`\/`), which you are telling it not to do (with `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`).

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` does not do what you *think* it does.

Comment: why are you building a JSON string manually, when PHP is capable of producing it for you? PS: your json is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = strip_slashes($arr);
```

or

```
$arr = str_replace("\\","", $arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` and it should work the way you want. If not, try using unicode encoding by using `JSON_HEX_APOS`.

Comment: This should probably be a comment until you have some level of confidence in your answer.